# If i am sending two request on single button click using Volley Library Then result is not getting as per expectation

Tags: android, android-volley

If i am requesting two different request(two different type Endpoint) on single button click using volley Library not getting as per expected result .

If i am calling two request on two different button click then result is proper .

I think volley is unable to handle multiple requests.

How can i get solve this  situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this  as a send first request if this is success then send second request under first request response

```
   first  request...
    respose{
    second request
  }
```

for more please follow this link

[Need to send multiple Volley Requests - in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228364/need-to-send-multiple-volley-requests-in-a-sequence)